# PHP Multibyte Regex to Search and Replace inner html needed

Tags: php, html, regex

This is bugging me the whole day now.
Assume this simple non valid HTML

```
<p clneck="something">my neck hurts</p>
```

Now I would like to use `preg_replace` to replace `neck` with `head`

Of course a simple

```
preg_replace("/neck/", "head")
```

would give me

```
<p clhead="something">my head hurts</p>
```

I guess you got the point.

I tried the build in DOMDocument, but it failed twice: it's not build for HTML5 and it still failed on some heavenly nested tags.

Comment: How did it fail? What did you try? Why did `ass` become `head` with that regex? These also aren't multibyte characters..

Comment: First of all check how to use [preg_replace](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_preg_replace.htm). You are missing third parameter. @chris85: I edited the question, so it's neck now :D

Comment: @noob aha makes a bit more sense now. I modified the `class` attribute to match, regex behavior. Still unclear on multibyte issue and OPs usages.

Comment: Why don't you use a DOM parser? http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Can be done by using backreferences like `$1`.

Simple example just handling p tags:

```
$input = '<p clneck="something">my neck hurts</p>';
$output = preg_replace('/(<p\s+[^>]+>[^<]*)neck([^<]*<\/p>)/i', '$1head$2', $input);
```

To handle all tags it gets a little bit more complicated, because we'll need references (`\\2`)in the matching regex, too:

```
$input = '<p clneck="something">my neck hurts</p><div idneck="foo">my neck hurts, too</div>';
$output = preg_replace('/(<(\w+)(\s+[^>]+)>[^<]*)neck([^<]*<\/\\2>)/i', '$1head$4', $input);
echo $output;
```

Comment: Not bad. But as far as I can see (before I test), this will only handle <p></p>. - What about all the other tags?

Comment: Adjusted my answer to handle all types of tags.